# UILabel Refresh

Tags: objective-c, xcode, refresh, uilabel

I have looked into this, but I’m still not quite clear how to do it.  I have a UILabel.  I would like to write out a word... letter by latter.  It goes through each letter, then at the end the entire word shows up.  At first I thought it was just because it was too fast, so I put in a delay with something like this.

```
    typedWord.text = [typedWord.text stringByAppendingString:@"C"];
    future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: letterPause ];
    [NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];
```

Then I read that it may be because it doesn’t refresh until the function call is finished.  The suggestion was to use a selector call.  I’m not sure how to do this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sleeping the main thread, so the UI is not getting refreshed until the end of the sleep.

You need to implement something like the following:

```
// This code is in your view controller somewhere, where you initially decide to update the label. typedWord is the outlet to your UILabel.
NSString *newText = @"Hello";
typedWord.text = @"";
[self performSelector:@selector(updateLabel:) withObject:newText afterDelay:0.2];
```

This calls:

```
// This is a separate method in your view controller, so typedWord still refers to the label outlet.
-(void)updateLabel:(NSString*)newText 
{
    // Get the first character of the passed in string
    NSString *firstCharacter = [newText substringToIndex:1];

    // Add this to whatever the current label text is
    typedWord.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",typedWord.text,firstCharacter];

    // Trim off the first character
    NSString *remainingCharacters = [newText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:@""];

    //If we still have characters left, do the loop again.
    if (![remainingCharacters isEqualToString:@""])
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateLabel:) withObject:remainingCharacters afterDelay:0.2];
}
```

Comment: [self performSelector:@selector(updateLabel:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.6];                                                    -(void)updateLabel:(NSString*)newString 
{
    NSLog(@"typedWord: %@\n",typedWord.text);
    NSLog(@"append: %@\n",newString);
    typedWord.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c",typedWord.text,newString];
}   I’m confused about the “typedWord.text”  I thought that was a global variable, but it turns to garbage inside there.  Sorry, this is totally new to me.

Comment: typedword is what I have assumed is the outlet variable to your label. Don't pass nil as the object either, this has to be the text you are using. If I get some time later I will put in a full code sample for you, I though your problem was with the performSelector only so I didn't flesh out that part of my answer, sorry.