# UILabel text not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

A UILabel in my .xib file that is hooked up to my .m file with an IBOutlet is not updating whether I try to set the text in the init file, viewDidLoad, or viewWillAppear. I ran into a similar problem four days ago ([Can't assign text to UILabel or pass NSString property when modally loading a view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26939981/cant-assign-text-to-uilabel-or-pass-nsstring-property-when-modally-loading-a-vi)), and the only thing that worked was deleting the view controller and its xib and starting over. I'd rather not have to do that, so I'm posting to see what else might solve this problem. Here's the code:

```
@interface LoginViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *session;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *notificationLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *username;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *password;

@property (nonatomic) int loggedin;

@end
```

I try to change the label with my initWithNibName:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];



    if(self){

        self.title=@"Followers & Following";

        self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"Follow";



        NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

        _session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];



        self.restorationIdentifier = NSStringFromClass([self class]);

        self.restorationClass = [self class];

        [self view];

        self.notificationLabel.text = @"Hello world"; ******************

        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

    }

    return self;

}
```

I also try to change it in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Login";



    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapBackground = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:)];

    [tapBackground setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapBackground];



            self.notificationLabel.text = @"Hello world"; ******************

            [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

and I do the same in viewWillAppear (I'll leave that out for brevity). The IBOutlet is hooked up, so I don't see what else could be going wrong. It will be quite annoying if I have to delete these files and start over just because - what else could be going wrong that I'm not checking?

Thank you.

Comment: First, set a breakpoint and confirm that the property isn't nil.  If it isn't then I would change the background colour or something in IB so that you can check that the field is actually visible and not off screen/too small/covered up

Comment: I can see the label when I run the app. It starts off as "Label".

Comment: Ok, then check the property isn't nil

Comment: I'm betting the property is nil.

Comment: No bet on that one :)

Comment: @Paulw11 So I put this into both initwithnib and viewdidload:    
    if(!self.notificationLabel)
    {
        NSLog(@"notification label is nil in viewdidload");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"notification label is not nil in view did load");
    } My output was: "notification label is not nil in view did load" but no message from init. No log messages are printing from init.

Comment: If isn't nil then it isn't pointing at the label you think it is.  Log the current value of its text property - change it from "label" in IB first

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't understand your comment about changing IB from "label". What would I change it to? I tried printing the text of the label,     
    if(!self.notificationLabel)
    {
        NSLog(@"notification label is nil in viewdidload");
        NSLog(@"here is label text%@", self.notificationLabel.text);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"notification label is not nil in view did load");
    } but actually this prints out nothing. It's as though the second line "here is label text" is never run.

Comment: Is this controller made in a xib or a storyboard?

Comment: @rdelmar storyboard.

Comment: Rather than logging, just set a breakpoint and examine the property in the debugger. The reason  I suggested changing the text is "label" is the default so if you get "label" in the log it may not confirm which label you printed. If you change it in in to something unique like " this is my label" then you know you definitely have the right one.

Comment: InitWithCoder: is the int method called for storyboard based controllers, not initWithNibName:bundle:

Comment: Also it looks like you have your if logic the wrong way around

Comment: @Paulw11 You're right.

Comment: Ok, so getting rid of the storyboard and initiating in app delegate solved the problem. First and last trial with storybord. Thank you!

Comment: You can certainly not use a storyboard if you want, but you must be doing something wrong with the way you're using a storyboard (in this question and the last). It might be good for you to figure out what that problem is.

Comment: I have been told they are good and getting better, and you are right in principle. But I find myself losing a lot of time and not quite knowing how to "debug" a storyboard problem. Any recommended readings?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "good and getting better" -- I've never had any trouble working with them. They have been adding features as time goes on, but they've been very functional since the beginning. I don't know any specific readings other than Apple's documentation. If you can post the version of your project that you had before you fixed it, I can look at it and tell you what you're doing incorrectly. I'm guessing that you have some fundamental, but probably simple misunderstanding of the way they are supposed to work.

Comment: @rdelmar Thank you for the offer, but I deleted it and did not save a copy with the storyboard. I only kept it as the place to load the root view controller- I was doing everything else problematically with xib files already, so this is more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Outlets will never be set in your init method, because the XIB file/storyboard isn't loaded at that point.

It should work in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:`. If it doesn't it probably means your outlet link is broken. That's the most common reason for code that works with outlets that seems like it should work but doesn't.